# get response from arduino using the command line

Tags: java, arduino

I've found it convenient to just execute "echo 1 >/dev/ttyACM0" from a java program to send commands to an arduino (in this case "1" toggles a relay attached to the arduino). Now I've decided that I'd like to get a response back from the arduino. Conceptually, what I'd like to do is simultaneously run echo and cat (read?) on the device so that I redirect what comes back from the device to stdout and then have my program capture that.

I know that I can do the whole thing in Java but that requires using multiple threads or opening and closing several files. Using echo makes it so easy, especially testing the sketch using the command line. So, is there a utility or shell script that does this?

Answer (score 0):

The terminal is a very powerful tool. Sending strings you use `echo` read output from Arduino use this code `tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0`. *replace USB0 with your serial bus*. There also is this command which I have tried once or twice but should work for anyone `screen /dev/cu.usbserial 9600` *replace 9600 with your port*.